# How to retrieve id from one table on the basis of string and store it as int in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a companyId **cid** which is a **int type**
 present in two tables

**companydet**

**opprt**

i have a problem that i'm trying to retrieve **cid** from **companydet** on the basis of **cname** comapny name which is string after retriving this id im trying to store it **opprt** which is an **int** type

i have tried this code

```
select c.cid 
from companydet c 
where cname='google' 
and insert into opprt( cid,oppdetails,oppfp,oppap,oppcd,oppd )
values('@c.cid','abc','','','','')
```

but its not working please help me with this and explain me how can we do this ?

Comment: You want select columns into newTable from oldTable where conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into opprt( cid, oppdetails, oppfp, oppap, oppcd, oppd )
    select c.cid, 'abc', '', '', '', ''
    from companydet c 
    where cname = 'google' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `insert...select` for this:

```
insert into opprt( cid,oppdetails,oppfp,oppap,oppcd,oppd )
select cid,'abc','','','',''
from companydet
where cname='google'
```

Answer (score 0):

to Insert into table using another table

```
insert into opprt( cid,oppdetails,oppfp,oppap,oppcd,oppd )
Select Columnname,Columnname1,Colummname2,Columnname3,...etc from companydet
where cname='google'
```

to insert values using static ones

```
insert into opprt( cid,oppdetails,oppfp,oppap,oppcd,oppd )
Values(cid,'abc','','','','')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use insert into .... select statement .
You have also disucss that cid in opprt is int and cid in companydet is varchar , so you need to cat cid to int .

Please follow my code .

```
 insert into opprt( cid,oppdetails,oppfp,oppap,oppcd,oppd )
    select CAST(cid as int),'abc','','','',''
    from companydet
    where cname='google'
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this too:

```
declare @d_cid int
select @d_cid = c.cid from companydet c where cname='google'
insert into opprt( cid,oppdetails,oppfp,oppap,oppcd,oppd )
values(@d_cid,'abc','','','','')
```